# Plotting Values along with Lat Lon in R

Tags: r, plot

I have extracted the Data from SQL which consists of fields like latitude, Longitude, and other values. which looks something like below:

```
Lat    Lon    Avg.Speed
79.4   33.5   0.56
78.5   33.5   0.46
```

and when I extracted the data saved in variable let say `C`.

Now I wanted to plot this data without saving this extracted information in any local folder in CSV, excel. i.e. wanted to directly plot values from variable `C`.

Would be really great to get help.

Comment: can you provide `dput(C)` ? Edit it into your question

Comment: also, plot as what? On a dynamic leaflet, on a static map, as a plain chart?

Comment: Static map needed for a while like this data is for chile so above chile only it will show.

Comment: And due to my limited knowledge would be great if you can suggest what is dput(C)

Comment: you saved the data to variable `C`. `dput(C)` gives the stricture of this variable. Paste it here, and we all can use it for answering.

Comment: Thanks but dput consist of huge data and same time my work not allowd me to provide.. To avoid this i have mentioned demo data above in question. Hope that will suffice.